# In JavaScript classes, you need to always call super? Confused about this statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently learning react and saw this line during the tutorial:

"In JavaScript classes, you need to always call super when defining the constructor of a subclass."

I thought the only time super() needed to be called was when you wanted to use properties of a parent class, and id you didn't need those properties you didn't have to call super(). I get it would be kind of pointless to create a child class that doesn't use properties from it's parent, but is the above statement true to JS or only to react?

Genuinely confused as a noob to web dev.

Comment: True for any JS class https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super#Description

Comment: If you don't, you'll get `Uncaught ReferenceError: Must call super constructor in derived class before accessing 'this' or returning from derived constructor`

Comment: @CertainPerformance I guess I can't @ both of you in a comment, but thanks for the reply both of you.

Comment: This is not about using or not using properties from a parent. `super()` isn't called by default because it's about passing necessary arguments to parent constructor and choosing a right place to call it. `super(...)` can take place anywhere in child constructor but earlier than the first occurrence of `this`.

Answer (score 6):

A subclass should always call parent's constructor, this should happen before `this` is accessed the first time in a subclass. This is deliberate limitation of ES6 classes. Otherwise it wouldn't be a subclass but something else.

The only case when a subclass *doesn't need* `super` is when it uses implicit constructor, i.e. it's inherited from a parent:

```
class Bar extends Foo {}
```

is a shortcut for

```
class Bar extends Foo {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
  }
}
```

This is common case in React, because explicit constructor is used relatively rare, while [class fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) are used often and are syntactic sugar for explicit constructor:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = { foo: this.props.foo };
  ...
}
```

is a shortcut for

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { foo: this.props.foo };
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a sub-class that doesn't use all of the parent class properties. That would defeat the point of defining a sub-class at all.

Imagine you have a class `Dog` and a sub-class `Labrador` which inherits from `Dog`. You would give the `Dog` class properties such as `tail` and `ears`. You can't then declare the sub-class `Labrador` and not give it a tail and ears because then it wouldn't be a dog.

The link Artyom provided shows another example; [you can't have a square without a length of the sides.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super#Description)

That's why super() needs to be called in a sub-class. Hope that helps!