# JavaScript subclass inheritance: unexpectedly works even without subclass constructor - why is it needed?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor

I'm looking through the MDN docs on classes, here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

but when playing with an example noticed that the output was identical even though I deleted the constructor in the subclass. I would have thought that the new instance of dog wouldn't be able to pass its property to the super class as it didn't use super(props) in its class definition

```
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  speak() {
    console.log(`${this.name} makes a noise.`);
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
//   constructor(name) {
//     super(name); 
//   }

  speak() {
    console.log(`${this.name} barks.`);
  }
}

let d = new Dog('Mitzie');
d.speak(); // "Mitzie barks" even though not calling super class constructor... or are we?!
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: if you put `console.log('Animal constructor called with', name)` in the Animal constructor, you'd see it is exectued - mystery solved

Comment: See also [In JavaScript classes, you need to always call super?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54164225/1048572) and [Extending class in JS without constructor or super()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58165634/1048572)

Answer (score 3):

When you don't specify a constructor *at all*, the JavaScript engine inserts a default one for you. In a base class, the default looks like this:

```
constructor() {
}
```

In a subclass, it look like this:

```
constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
}
```

As you can see, in a subclass the default constructor passes along all of its arguments to the superclass constructor, which explains why Mitzie barks. :-)

See [Step 10 of *Runtime Semantics: ClassDefinitionEvaluation*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-classdefinitionevaluation).

Comment: So there is a default constructor behaviour here, thanks for the illumination

Comment: @BBrow - Yup. Quite a useful default. (Not sure why I didn't use the word "default" in the answer, actually... I should add it.)

Answer (score 1):

If you omit it, you get a default constructor that just calls the superclasses constructor with the arguments.

So it isn't needed … unless you want the override the constructor so that the subclass does something different or extra when you construct it.

Comment: Thanks for the input - I thought that the subclass speak method is overriding the superclasses' speak method, which it does without the constructor. Can you give an example of overriding the super class constructor?

Comment: This answer seems to be a good example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55760091/how-to-override-a-base-class-constructor-in-javascript