# Extending class in JS without constructor or super()

Tags: javascript, extends, super, es6-class

I am learning JS and I am told that if I want to extend a class I need to use a constructor and super().
But when I was experimenting I discovered that I can extend the class without. I tried to find an explanation on the internet but couldn't find one. Can somebody explain to me? Thanks

```
class Person {
  constructor(name, email, address) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.adress = address;
  }

}

class Employee extends Person {
  getName() {
    return (
      "Hi!," +
      this.name +
      " who has " +
      this.email +
      " as email and lives in " +
      this.adress
    );
  }
}

const newEmployee = new Employee("Ahmed", "ahmed@test.com", "Beverly Hills");

console.log(newEmployee.getName()); *// Hi!,Ahmed who has ahmed@test.com as email and lives in Beverly Hills*
```

Comment: Using `super` in your constructor is needed only if you define a constructor that does something different. If you define a constructor in `Employee` and call `new Employee` the *that* constructor gets called, not the one in `Person`.

Comment: See also [In JavaScript classes, you need to always call super?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54164225/1048572) and [JavaScript subclass inheritance unexpectedly works even without subclass constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57767883/1048572)

Answer (score 2):

Super method is used to call parent's constructor.
You can use it if you need it (using the logic of your parent class in your derived class), but it's not mandatory.
You can create a class without constructor, but it will use a default one

```
constructor() {}
```

For the derived class, if you don't specify a constructor, it will use

```
constructor(...args) {
  super(...args);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation for [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor)'s, on [Default constructors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor#Default_constructors).

> For derived classes, the default constructor is:
>
> ```
>  constructor(...args) {
>     super(...args);
>  }
> ```

which means that the default constructor already has the call for `super` in it, along with the default dependencies of its base class (`...args` in your case is `name, email, address`).

If you define your own constructor for your derived class `Employee`, you will have to call the `super()` with the said dependencies.

As to **why** do you have to call super, you may read more from another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31079103/2678218) by [loganfsmyth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/785065/loganfsmyth).

Answer (score 0):

you may not need super() if you are not adding a new property to the sub class. but if you need to add a new property to the sub class, you have to use call super()